# How to Clear Document in Express or Socket.io

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I'm using a combination of Express and Socket.io (which isn't uncommon), and I'm trying to accomplish what `document.write()` would accomplish (JavaScript). Is there a way to accomplish this? Could I simply `res.send()` the string `<script>document.write(//blah)</script>`? Would this be possible?

Comment: There's way too little detail here to have any idea what you're really trying to do.  There's no real point in putting `<script>document.write("someContent");</script>` into a response.  You may as well just insert the content directly and not use `document.write()` at all.  And, `io.emit()` sends data, not an HTML page so no scripts make sense there.  Show your WHOLE problem including your code and exactly what you are trying to achieve if you  want actual help.

Comment: Please show us your actual Express and socket.io code.  Questions about code should include the relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm using a combination of Express and Socket.io (which isn't uncommon), and I'm trying to accomplish what document.write() would accomplish (JavaScript).

Well, there's your problem.

Express and Socket.IO are server-side technologies and have absolutely nothing to do with pages in your browser.  You'll need some client-side code for that.